# Import gpx track using the XML library

Tags: xml, r, gpx

I want to analyse a gpx track in R. To import the data, I try to use the [XML-package](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/XML/index.html).

I found [a tutorial](http://www.r-bloggers.com/stay-on-track-plotting-gps-tracks-with-r/) that explained how to import each individual data vector and then combine them to a data frame.

However, in my usecase this does not work, because for some nodes there was no heart rate `<gpxtpx:hr>` collected, so the length of the vectors would not match.

Therefore I try to import all relevant data at once.

What I manage to do so far is

```
library(XML)

filename <- "sample.gpx"
download.file("https://owncloud.yeara.net/index.php/s/Io4uOq6sfFuCCdq/download", filename) # downloads a sample file from my server

gpx.raw <- xmlTreeParse(filename, useInternalNodes = TRUE)

rootNode <- xmlRoot(gpx.raw)

print(rootNode) # output seems okay
```

Now, instead of the rootNode, I'd like to import the content of `<trkseg>` into a dataframe. It should be designed in the following way:

- Each `trkseg` should be a row
- `trkpt lon`, `trkpt lat`, `<ele>` and `<time>` should be in corresponding columns
- If there is a value `<gpxtpx:hr>` it should also go into the corresponding column

Can you help me to achieve this?

Comment: Can you show the code you have so far for doing this processing ?  Can you just create a function that process the appropriate node, which would provide a default when the "hr" child doesn't exist ?

Comment: The code I used so far is linked in my question: http://www.r-bloggers.com/stay-on-track-plotting-gps-tracks-with-r/ or `elevations <- as.numeric(xpathSApply(gpx.raw, path = "//trkpt/ele", xmlValue))` (and similar). This however doesn't seem quite elegant as it always imports the columns one by one. From the structure of the gpx file it shoult (at least in theory) be possible to import all relevant data at once. If this is not possible, there might be a way to replace all missing `hr` nodes with `NA`

Comment: Flattening nested xml stuff is (imho) always a pain. Try sth like `lst <- xmlToList(rootNode);do.call(plyr::rbind.fill, lapply(lst$trk$trkseg, function(x) as.data.frame(t(unlist(x)), stringsAsFactors=F)))` for a starter. _"Each trkseg should be a row"_ - what if each trkseg holds several lon/lat/etc values, i.e. if it may hold for more than one row?

Comment: thank you! I don't know but aren't xml distinct per definition? I think at least in gpx it should be. But I will try it...

Comment: Or you could just use `plotKML::readGPX()`

Comment: Thank you @hrbrmstr I looked at plotKML already. If I am not mistaken (I tried a lot of packages on that day) plotKML has quite a big footprint (I had to install quite a bunch of packages which partially were quite big) and produced a somewhat "cumbersome" output. Therefore I still try to do it "by hand". But still: thank you for the hint!

Comment: But, the source for `plotKML:::.readGPX.element()` prbly has enough hints to get you started and seems to be pretty self-contained to just requiring the `XML` pkg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the code I ended up with. Thanks to all of you (especially @lukeA) for your help.

```
library(XML)
library(plyr)

filename <- "Downloads/activity(1).gpx"

gpx.raw <- xmlTreeParse(filename, useInternalNodes = TRUE)

rootNode <- xmlRoot(gpx.raw)

gpx.rawlist <- xmlToList(rootNode)$trk

gpx.list <- unlist(gpx.rawlist[names(gpx.rawlist) == "trkseg"], recursive = FALSE)

gpx <- do.call(rbind.fill, lapply(gpx.list, function(x) as.data.frame(t(unlist(x)), stringsAsFactors=F)))
names(gpx) <- c("ele", "time", "hr", "lon", "lat")
```

I had some trouble with multiple `trkseg`s as I could not access them by name (because they all have the same name in the list: `trkseg`) I could solve this with the `unlist` command and the tricky selection of elements in `gpx.rawlist`.

I wonder if there is a more elegant way, but at least this seems to work.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a version similar to the answer from @speendo, but using dplyr and purrr:

```
library(XML)
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)

filename <- "Downloads/activity(1).gpx"

gpx <- filename %>%
  xmlTreeParse(useInternalNodes = TRUE) %>%
  xmlRoot %>%
  xmlToList %>%
  (function(x) x$trk) %>%
  (function(x) unlist(x[names(x) == "trkseg"], recursive = FALSE)) %>%
  map_df(function(x) as.data.frame(t(unlist(x)), stringsAsFactors=FALSE))
```